# Github.io could not find artifact:

Tags: git, maven, github

Seems like I can't find an artifact in github.io. from a maven project.

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project 
org.Project_Name: Could not find artifact 
es.Artifact_Name in maven-nuxeo 
(https://maven.nuxeo.org/nexus/content/groups/public/)
```

This artifact is in the respository:

```
http://company_name.github.io/.../maven
```

That's included in the pom.xml of the module, and I can see this artifact on

```
github.com/../maven
```

But anyway,copying the urls from the error I can't see the file from github.io. The URL is:

```
github.io/.../maven/../Artifact_Name
```

Also I noticed that the url from github.com includes the branch like:

```
github.com/../maven/tree/branchname/maven/..
```

while github.io is written without specifying the branch, like:

```
http://company_name.github.io/../maven/maven/..
```

In case it helps, the last instruction displayed in console from maven is:

```
Downloading from github-company-maven-repos: http://company_name.github.io/maven/maven/es/org/repo/repo-apirest/1.0.8/Artifact_Name-1.0.8.jar
Downloading from repo-maven-apache-org: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/es/org/repo/repo-apirest/1.0.8/Artifact_Name-1.0.8.jar
```

The question: Is there any error with the urls, or any recent change in github.io that makes any of the urls not functional anymore? I am already aware of the recent change that there can't be capital letters in the urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, github.io accepts capital letters again and it's case sensitive.